# react-native: shadow of a fixed header go below the scrollView

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a header with fixed position at the top of the View, then a scrollView. when scrollView scrolled, it's going under the header. it's ok but header shadow will removed in the center and remain on the edge. How can fix shadow so it's not change by scrolling the scrollView?

I'm using `flex: 0` for attaching header to the top of the page, if i use `position:'absolute'` there is not shadow problem. How can i have shadow with `flex: 0`?

[image of the header & scroolView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC9BI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

you should use [zIndex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#zindex). Then your header will display on top of the scrollView and have the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of "yourView.layer.zPosition". Making the value higher will prioritize the view, respect to other views on screen.

Comment: How can i do that in react native?